# How to handle multiple ResultSets, each with multiple Rows? IDataReader.NextResult() ending Read()

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, datareader

How to handle multiple ResultSets, each with multiple Rows?
The call to `NextResult()` breaks the while loop.

Some of my SPs return multiple ResultSets. I'm handling these with `NextResult()` but when I do and my SP only has a single ResultSet, I see the while loop with Read() finishes leaving me with only the first Row.

Without the call to `NextResult()` I get all the rows for the first ResultSet but of course the second and subsequent ResultSets don't get processed?

```
using (IDataReader reader = storedProcedure.ExecuteReader(
    CommandBehavior.CloseConnection, parameterNames as string[], arguments))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        ArrayList row = new ArrayList();
        for (int j = 0; j < reader.FieldCount; ++j)
        {
            object rowValue = reader.GetValue(j);

            row.Add(rowValue);
        }

        reader.NextResult();//next resultset, breaks out of the  while
    }
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to create two nested loops.

- The outer loop should iterate over result sets and should have `NextResult` at the end
- The inner loop should iterate over rows in a result set and should have `Read` at the beginning.

Something like:

```
using (IDataReader reader = ...) { 
  // Process all result sets
  do {
    // Process all elements in the current result set
    while (reader.Read()) { 
      ArrayList row = new ArrayList(); 
      for (int j = 0; j < reader.FieldCount; ++j) { 
        object rowValue = reader.GetValue(j); 
        row.Add(rowValue); 
      } 
      // TODO: Do something with 'row'
    }
  } while (reader.NextResult())
}
```

Comment: This was great. I so rarely come across do-while loops anymore that I forgot it even existed and thus never thought to use one until seeing this. Thank you!

Comment: Perfect sitch for a do/while structure